# mvn archetype:generate -B^でエラーになる

Tags: maven

下記のサイトを参考にWindowsでSpring BootプロジェクトをMaven Archetypeから作成したいのですが、
コマンドプロンプトからコマンドを実行する(斜線部分が入力)とエラーになります。

#[https://spring-boot-camp.readthedocs.io/ja/latest/01-HelloWorld.html][1]

C:\Users>*mvn archetype:generate -B^*
More? *-DarchetypeGroupId=am.ik.archetype^*
More? *-DarchetypeArtifactId=spring-boot-docker-blank-archetype^*
More? *-DarchetypeVersion=1.0.2^*
More? *-DgroupId=kanjava^*
More? *-DartifactId=kusokora^*
More? *-Dversion=1.0.0-SNAPSHOT*

【エラー文言】
Unable to parse command line options: Unrecognized option

コマンドはコピペしているため打ち間違いの可能性はなく、
他のサイトの同様のサンプルでも同じエラーになります。
（エラーを見ると打ち間違いの可能性もありそうですが…。）

事前準備が足りないのか、実行する場所が悪いなどのやり方が間違っているのかわからない状況です。

どこに問題があることが想定されますでしょうか。

■バージョン
Apache Maven 3.8.6

Comment: 頂戴したご指摘通り各行の先頭に半角スペースが必要であり、追加したら実行できました。大変助かりました。ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

各行の頭にスペースがないので、オプションがつながってるように解釈されていますかね。

```
mvn archetype:generate -B^
 -DarchetypeGroupId=am.ik.archetype^
 -DarchetypeArtifactId=spring-boot-docker-blank-archetype^
 -DarchetypeVersion=1.0.2^
 -DgroupId=kanjava^
 -DartifactId=kusokora^
 -Dversion=1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
```

とするとうまくいくかと思います。

作ってみた結果は以下の通り

```
└─kusokora
│  pom.xml
│
└─src
    ├─main
    │  ├─docker
    │  │      Dockerfile.txt
    │  │      Dockerrun.aws.json
    │  │
    │  ├─java
    │  │  └─kanjava
    │  │          App.java
    │  │
    │  └─resources
    │          application.yml
    │
    └─test
        ├─java
        │      .gitkeep
        │
        └─resources
                .gitkeep
```